# In Matlab, how to apply an 'AggregationFunction' with two variables in unstack?

Tags: matlab, pivot-table, matlab-table

**Objective:**
I would like to get, for each period and group of a timetable, the result of a given function of var1 and var2 [i.e. the ratio of (the sum of var1 over the group) by (the sum of var2 over the group)]
using [unstack](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unstack.html) and a function handle:

**Data**

```
A = [1 2 3 4 2 4 6 8]';
B = [4 2 14 7 8 4 28 14]';
C=["group1";"group1";"group2";"group2";"group1";"group1";"group2";"group2"];
Year = [2010 2010 2010 2010 2020 2020 2020 2020]';
Year = datetime(string(Year), 'Format', 'yyyy');
t=table(Year,C,A,B,'VariableNames',{'Year' 'group' 'var1' 'var2'});
t=table2timetable(t,'RowTimes','Year');
```

**Desired Output** [EDIT]

A table with three columns: year, Ratio_group1, Ratio_group2. Where for instance:
Ratio_group1 for 2010 = (1+2) / (4+2) =0.5.

**Function**

```
f = @(x,y) sum(x)./sum(y);   %or f = @(x) sum(x(1,:))./sum(x(2,:));
[Ratio,is] = unstack(t,{'var1','var2'},"group",'AggregationFunction',f);
```

**Errors that I get:**

```
%Not enough input arguments.
%Or: Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1)
```

**Another failed test** inspired from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.groupsummary.html
(See Method Function Handle with Multiple Inputs)

```
[Ratio,is] = unstack(t,{["var1"],["var2"]},"group",'AggregationFunction',f);
%Error: A table variable subscript must be a numeric array continaing real positive integers, a logical array (...)
```

Comment: I asked the same question on the Matlab website: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/659973-how-to-apply-an-aggregationfunction-with-two-variables-in-unstack
I will signal here if it gets answered there.

Comment: What's the desired output in this specific example? How are periods defined? That is, is each year a period, or is it more complicated? And, do you really need to do it with `unstack`, or is some other (vectorized) approach acceptable, such as `splitapply(@(x,y) sum(x)/sum(y), t.var1, t.var2, findgroups(t.Year, t.group))`?

Comment: Thank you very. Each year is a period. I would accept in priority an answer based on unstack ; but if there is none, and if you transform your comment into an answer, I will obviously accept your answer based on splitapply.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) (or equivalently [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)):

```
result = splitapply(@(x,y) sum(x)/sum(y), t.var1, t.var2, findgroups(t.Year, t.group));
```